# Cells size in gird layout [android]

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I work on android app to **display tables**

I am using **GirdLayout** for that, with span first row , but second row is different  size of cells .

**How can make all cells same width ?**

[image]

when use ( fill parent or match parent ) !

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly, you can use weights to fill the screen width, Example:

```
<GridLayout
android:id="@+id/my_grid"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:padding="2dp"
grid:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
grid:columnCount="2"  
grid:rowOrderPreserved="false"
grid:useDefaultMargins="true">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="my text1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="my text2" />

    ...

    </GridLayout>
```